# Delphi TPair Exception

Tags: delphi, generics, exception, delphi-xe

I have this spike to test TPair.  You can copy+paste on a new Delphi XE Console-app.  I have marked the line with the exception:

> Project Project1.exe raised exception
>   class EAccessViolation with message
>   'Access violation at address 0045042D
>   in module 'Project1.exe'.  Read of
>   address A9032D0C.

Any Idea ?

Thanks.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  Generics.Defaults,
  Generics.Collections;

type
  TProduct = class
  private
    FName: string;
    procedure SetName(const Value: string);
  published
  public
    property Name: string read FName write SetName;
  end;

type
  TListOfProducts = TObjectDictionary<TProduct, Integer>;

{ TProduct }

procedure TProduct.SetName(const Value: string);
begin
  FName := Value;
end;


var
  MyDict: TListOfProducts;
  MyProduct1: TProduct;
  MyProduct2: TProduct;
  MyProduct3: TProduct;
  APair: TPair<TProduct, Integer>;
  aKey: string;

begin
  try
    MyDict := TListOfProducts.Create([doOwnsKeys]);
    MyProduct1 := TProduct.Create;
    MyProduct1.Name := 'P1';
    MyProduct2 := TProduct.Create;
    MyProduct2.Name := 'P2';
    MyProduct3 := TProduct.Create;
    MyProduct3.Name := 'P3';

    MyDict.Add(MyProduct1, 1);
    MyDict.Add(MyProduct2, 2);
    MyDict.Add(MyProduct3, 3);

    APair := MyDict.ExtractPair(MyProduct1);
    Writeln(APair.Key.Name);   // <--- Error is Here.
    Writeln(IntToStr(APair.Value));

    Readln(aKey);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: You say `// <--- Error is Here.`, but you don't say what the error actually is. Knowing that makes it easier to help when you don't have a copy of XE installed on the machine you're reading SO from at the minute.

Comment: Sorry... I have added the concrete exception error message.

Comment: It's a mystery, I can't for the life of me see a problem!

Comment: Do you mean all source code is right ?  That would be worse...  :-(  Can you reproduce the problem in your Delphi IDE installation ?

Comment: If I add this line: `APair := TPair<TProduct, Integer>.Create(MyProduct3, 0);` before the `ExtractPair` sentence, then I have no excepcion but also I have no `MyProduct1` data inside the `APair` var.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a Delphi bug.  `TDictionary<TKey,TValue>.ExtractPair` does not assign `Result`.

RRUZ located the [bug in QC](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=80947).

The code reads:

```
function TDictionary<TKey,TValue>.ExtractPair(const Key: TKey): TPair<TKey,TValue>;
var
  hc, index: Integer;
begin
  hc := Hash(Key);
  index := GetBucketIndex(Key, hc);
  if index < 0 then
    Exit(TPair<TKey,TValue>.Create(Key, Default(TValue)));

  DoRemove(Key, hc, cnExtracted);
end;
```

`Result` should be assigned when the call to `DoRemove` is made.

It's quite hard to work around this bug.  `ExtractPair` is the only way to get an item out of the dictionary without destroying the key and so you have to call it. But since it won't return the extracted item, you need to first read the item, remember the value, and then call `ExtractPair`.

Comment: @David, is allowed post Delphi RTL source code in public forums?

Comment: @RRUZ I don't see a problem with a one-off routine. Especially when we are debugging the VCL. Do you agree with me that this is a straightforward bug in the VCL code?

Comment: @David, i found a QC report about this issue, but i don't know if that is a bug or is by design. because the use of the `doOwnsKeys`, i think which someone as @Barry Kelly (or another embarcadero employee) can explain better this. i cannot found any similar function in .Net dictionary class to compare the behavior.

Comment: @Rruz, U.S. law allows the reproduction of limited portions of copyrighted works for the purposes of review and critique, among other things. It's known as *fair use*. I'm sure David's answer meets the criteria.

Comment: @RRUZ It can't be by design that a function doesn't assign it's return value. The `doOwnsKeys` issue is a side-issue here, it doesn't impact one way or another on an extract function. The issue of specification and lack of documentation is an issue for the key not found case, but it's clear what ExtractPair must do if the key is found. And it doesn't do it.

Comment: @RRUZ That QC report is indeed the same bug. It's very disappointing that the QC system doesn't result in such obvious bugs being fixed. Remember that this was reported 16 months ago!

Comment: @David, i can't speculate about the `ExtractPair` function because the lack of documentation, but i Agree with you about a function always must return a value. but I differ in your opinion about the `doOwnsKeys` value because this impact directly in the objects holded by the dictionary. I Don't see how the `ExtractPair` will return a `TPair` with the Key value released. sorry if I'm not very clear expressing my thoughts in English.

Comment: @RRUZ Understanding `doOwnsKeys` is pretty easy. It simply cannot affect how `ExtractPair` behaves since `ExtractPair` returns a key. `ExtractPair` could hardly free the key that it returns. `TList.Extract` and `TList.OwnsObjects` behave the same way. `doOwnsKeys` only affects what happens when you call `Delete`, `Remove`, `Clear` etc. These are all routines that do not return a value and so it is reasonable for them to free objects that are being deleted from the list.

Comment: @RRUZ As for the lack of documentation, there is a strong precedent for list classes and names like `Insert`, `Add`, `Delete`, `Remove`, `Extract`, `Clear` etc. are all well understood and what you know about them in the context of `Classes.TList` transfers across to the new generics collections.

Comment: @David, my bad I delete my answer because I misunderstand the `DoRemove` procedure called inside of the `ExtractPair` function (and because that i made wrong assumptions about the `ExtractPair`), the call to this method does not release the object when is called using the `cnExtracted` flag. and now do you make me change my mind. +1 for you.

Comment: @RRUZ I've updated my answer to include the QC report you found and to outline how to work around the bug. If you think I have missed something or am in error, please feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: Doesn't the compiler return a warning in such case? If not, is it because of the new Exit() syntax? It's a pity such a bug exists in the VCL, for such a common unit. Should have been trapped with unitary regression tests, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks to all people for your answers and this interesting discuss.

Comment: @A.Bouchez the compiler would report a warning when the VCL source is compiled.

Comment: @David I found it quite unbelievable that those warnings were not handled by the EMB team. IMHO any serious Delphi project should avoid any warning at compilation, or explicitly use compiler directive around ambiguous code when necessary (e.g. platform depended code).

Comment: @A.Bouchez Indeed. The other thing that gets me is that the bug gets reported to QC and then they make another major release that retains the bug. This happens far too often.